# AlertDialog with one button to reset application

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my AlertDialog, I added only one button. When I click to this button, I hope that I return to the home.

This is the code :

```
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Débit !!");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Votre débit de téléchargement est "+deb);
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                     

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            } 
        });
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        alertDialog.show();
```

I know that I need to add some Lines in `public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)`. But, I don't kniw what I'll put in.

Please, I need your suggestion.

Comment: What is the "home" the home activity of your app or just go to the home screen period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to go to a certaint activity within your application this should do it.

```
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                     

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

         Intent i = new Intent(Your_class.this, YOur_class_you_want_to_start.class);
         startActivity(i);



        } 
    });
```